# Changements des Echelles xy

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

Je travail dans QGIS 3.34.0 et je doit decouper un Raster a des petits blocs de quelques centimetres et les transformer en STL pour les imprimer en 3D. Mais j'ai rencontrer enormements des problemes au niveau des echelles. Pour decouper le Raster a des petits blocs de taille precise j'avais prevue d'utuliser une couche grille, mais l'algorithme n'arrivent pas a généré une grille qui comporte des blocs des tailles minipar ce que le logicielle utulise la taille réels malgré que j'ai changé l'echelle du projets. D'hailleure le logiciel ne prend pa

Comment: Unfortunatelly, GIS SE does not speak your language, please, make it English

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. The site requires all questions and answers to be in English.

Comment: Merci de mettre la question en anglais et de la completer/ Please translate your question to English and make sure it is complete